# How to switch to english layout on keyboard when esc is pressed?

Tags: windows, vim, keyboard-layout

I have windows 10 and two keyboard layouts. Sometimes I forget to switch from my secondary layout to english. I always have to switch to English when I press Esc key (especially in Vim). How can I bind Esc key to switch to English layout? I'm lookin' for any solution. Key-mapper, macros, software, OS hack, etc.

Comment: this might help https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/230/how-can-i-modify-vim-to-work-with-a-different-keyboard-layout

Comment: I considered this option, but I have a lot of vim emulators and they don't have this option

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/).

It lets you remap a key, with or without consuming it (i.e. it can still function as itself as well), across the system or only when a certain window is in focus (e.g. Vim).

First, you should make a shortcut for switching specifically to the English layout, rather than switch to the "other one." I have 4 layouts (languages) on my computer; <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> switches to the next one, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> always switches to English. To do this, go to Control Panel > Clock, Language, and Region > Language > Advanced settings (in the sidebar), then under "Switching input methods" click on the "Change language bar hot keys" and pick a shortcut for switching to English.

Here's an example for an AutoHotkey script that makes the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> whenever it's pressed while a window with the word "Vim" in its title is active:

```
#IfWinActive, Vim
~Escape::^1
```

Download the program, put the code in a script file (*.ahk) and run it.
If you want the mapping to work across the system, remove the first line.

You can find more information about how to use the various keys in a script [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).